How to combine an editable DT datatable, a modular app structure and an app-to-toplevel communication?
In my shiny project the UI and server functions grow unwieldy, so I'm modularizing and having trouble with arganization. The underlying issue is that the top level app has shiny::uiOutput containers, that I would like to fill/control out of the various modules that correspond to functional elements in my app. A particularly thorny aspect follows.
Based on the answer here, the following app works for me (editing DT contents get detected and reacted to):
requireNamespace("shiny")
requireNamespace("DT")

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::titlePanel("Place Holder Version"),
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      shiny::uiOutput("TextPlaceholder")),
    shiny::mainPanel(
      shiny::uiOutput("DTPlaceholder"))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$DTPlaceholder <- shiny::renderUI(DT::dataTableOutput("DT"))
  output$DT <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE,
    rownames = TRUE,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
      paging = TRUE,
      searching = TRUE,
      fixedColumns = TRUE,
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      ordering = TRUE,
      dom = 'Bfrtip',
      buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
    ),
    class = "display")
  shiny::observeEvent(input$DT_cell_edit, {
    output$TextPlaceholder <- shiny::renderUI(
      shiny::markdown('<span style="color:red"> **Data was edited**</span>'))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


I am now struggling with wrapping this all up into a modular structure including module-to-toplevel communication with respect to the observing of edits and the reaction to them). @Limey pointed me at session$userData in the comments and based on that I was able to come up with a modularized version that displays the DT on the top level - but the sensing of editing does not work.
requireNamespace("shiny")
requireNamespace("DT")

datatableUI <- function(id = "datatable")
{
  shiny::tagList(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      shiny::uiOutput("LocalTextPlaceholder")))
}

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::titlePanel("Module Version"),
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      shiny::uiOutput("TextPlaceholder")),
    shiny::mainPanel(
      datatableUI(),
      shiny::uiOutput("DTPlaceholder"))))

datatableServer <- function(id = "datatable")
{
  shiny::moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session)
  {
    session$userData$DT <- DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE,
      rownames = TRUE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        paging = TRUE,
        searching = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        ordering = TRUE,
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
      ),
      class = "display")
    observeEvent(
      session$userData$DTinput,
      {
        output$LocalTextPlaceholder <- shiny::renderUI(
          shiny::markdown(
            '<span style="color:red"> **Data was edited**</span>'))
        session$userData$Text <- shiny::markdown(
          '<span style="color:red"> **Data was edited**</span>')
      }
    )
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$userData$DTinput <- shiny::reactive(input$DTPlaceholder_cell_edit)
  datatableServer()
  shiny::observeEvent(
    session$userData$DT,
    {
      output$DTPlaceholder <- shiny::renderUI(session$userData$DT)
    }
  )
  shiny::observeEvent(
    session$userData$Text, ignoreInit = TRUE,
    {
      output$TextPlaceholder <- shiny::renderUI(session$userData$Text)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

How would I fix about that?

So is it really the case that I cannot hand anything into the top/level name space when operating in a module name space?

Your module serve functions need to return a reactive.  The app's main server function can monitor that reactive and respond to changes.  Similarly, you can pass the reactive returned by one module as input to another module's server function if you need inter module communication (though I prefer to use session$userData for that.  You can find more information from Posit here.

My answer here may also be helpful.

Ha. session$userData is an eye opener indeed, Do I get this right, that observers at the toplevel of the app could watch session$userData$myfield and whenever any module changes that object the toplevel will react?

@Limey: The one way connection (DT to toplevel uiOutput) I was able to set up using session$userData and adapted the question accordingly; can you spot why the reverse (observing the editing and reporting the edited state to the module does not appear to work?

session$userData$DTinput is a reactive (a function).  session$userData$DTinput() is the reactive's (function's) value.  So I think you you need observeEvent(session$userData$DTinput(), {...}) in your datatable server function (because the reactive doesn't change, but its value does).

Earlier version of comment was a red herring. Observed handler error was due to me erroneously using DT::datatable rather than DT::renderDataTable. Fixed.now.

Also posted at the DT source now.
